# Html code Email : it does not work the same as the Tryit Editor

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

everyone, I hope you can help me with a question I have ... I saw some examples and I edited it to be able to make the body of an email, and be able to send it by gmail and other email providers ... I have tried it in Tryit Editor and it works well:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSKBT3UW23J3

but in the end what comes is this:

```
Featured
Special title treatment

With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.

Go somewhere
Social Media

Legal
Terms & Privacy

Contact Information
Tell: 506 8888-8888
Email: support@youcompany.com Web: www.dominio.com
```

I do not take capture, because only text without style comes, as I have put in the box, I hope you can clarify that I am doing wrong and I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Most email clients strip the head tag from the email, so the bootstrap and fontawesome link tags as well as the style tag in your head are probably all being stripped leaving the email with just the bare content from your html inside the body tag. In addition, most email clients block javascript, so your script tags at the bottom of the html body are probably not having any effect either. Coding html email for consistent display in various email clients is tricky - check out [Common HTML Mistakes - Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/help/common-html-mistakes/) for some general guidance.

Your best bet is to code the email without any javascript and include your styles inline in the html or in a style tag inside the html body without relying on external stylesheets. An example basic html email structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Email Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- put your email content in an html table and use inline styles -->
  <table></table>

  <!-- 
  you can also use css in a style tag inside the body
  but some clients may not handle this as well as inline styles
  -->
  <style type="text/css"></style>

</body>
</html>
```